# Python in Vs-Code: Can't import python file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import

When i try to run main.py, this error appears: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catalog'

```
main.py

from catalog.config import config
from catalog.config.log_config import app_logging_config
from catalog.es_catalog_controller import EsCatalogController

@lru_cache()
def get_settings():
    return config.Settings()


catalog_controller = EsCatalogController()
```

It seems that vscode does not recognize the import of files inside catalog folder, but in pycharm it runs normally. What is needed to vscode recognizes this kind of import?

Comment: By default, PyCharm adds the project root to the PYTHONPATH so that Python can find modules there. I don't know whether VSCode does or doesn't, but the issue is likely that you need to add the location the module is at to the Python path. You can do that either from code, or in the environment from VSCode.

Comment: did you tick "add to path" while installing python. If not, then reinstall or add it to path see guide from internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shortcut **"ctrl+shift+P"** and choose the **"python:select interpreter"**:

[image]

You can also click the option in the red box in the lower right corner to specify the python version:

[image]

After specifying the correct Python interpreter, install package by using command `pip install catalog`.

Answer (score -1):

make a virtual machine and then try. If u still get the error then u put the files in